# Why are chinese characters still not showing in eclipse?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, utf-8, chinese-locale

Even after using the guide from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/) to set the `UTF-8` encoding, I went on and restarted eclipse but the text are still showing as weird characters like in my screenshot below.

[image]

Please advise what else can I do.

Comment: Make sure your source file is in correct encoding.

Comment: those weird chars are string literals... is your ide formatting to utf-8 too?

Comment: Your GUI is showing exactly what is in the source.

Comment: @dpassy how do i check that?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  i'm sure i did the setting, Window / Preferences / General / Workspace / Text file encoding > Other > UTF-8. Still not showing the chinese characters though.

Answer (score 0):

The guide you followed appears to be for text in the Eclipse *console*, while your problem is in the code editor. In my case (Neon.3) I solved that by setting UTF-8 in Window / Preferences / General / Workspace / Text file encoding.

Comment: i'm also using the same Neon.3, done the setting like u advised and restarted eclipse. Still the same though

Comment: @Ronaldo Maybe your files use a different encoding than UTF-8. You could try selecting another value from that list.

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is about encoding the output in the eclipse console, you are using GUIs from java swing, on the other hand, what you are doing is not enough, the **gui** label is printing **EXACTLY** the value that the string literal is holding... you need to set the encoding **utf-8** to files too:

[image]

Comment: Done this and restarted eclipse. It's still the same.